# Scala trait example not working as it should

Tags: scala

I am trying to run tutorialspoint example

```
trait Equal {
   def isEqual(x: Any): Boolean
   def isNotEqual(x: Any): Boolean = !isEqual(x)
}

class Point(xc: Int, yc: Int) extends Equal {
   var x: Int = xc
   var y: Int = yc

   def isEqual(obj: Any) = obj.isInstanceOf[Point] && obj.asInstanceOf[Point].x == y
}

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val p1 = new Point(2, 3)
      val p2 = new Point(2, 4)
      val p3 = new Point(3, 3)

      println(p1.isNotEqual(p2))
      println(p1.isNotEqual(p3))
      println(p2.isNotEqual(2))
   }
}
```

I got no print on screen if I run from terminal

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~$ scala d8.scala
```

If I run code from eclipse,then I have
[image]

Why do I have problem with this simple example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be missing a few steps in the edit-compile-run loop, because it works fine for me.

```
prompt> vi demo.scala      # input your code here
prompt> scalac demo.scala  # compile the code, creates .class files
prompt> scala Demo         # object Demo has a "main" method
true
false
true
prompt>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile first

```
scalac d8.scala
```

then

```
scala Demo
```

The scala command wont run source files if they have traits